# Modifying img src using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, image, innerhtml

I'm so close to finishing my code, but I'm stuck on this one little last hurdle. I want the code to allow the user to enter a link, and then when they click the button, the page appends the actual image by modifying the img src. I also want it wo append the image by using an unordered list.

Here's what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Images Reveal</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = alert('Welcome to my assignment 2!')

        $(document).keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                alert('Please submit text via button');
            }
        });

        var string = "";

        function imageReveal() {
            var rubberDuckie = document.getElementById("textInput");
            var imageReveal = rubberDuckie.value;
            if (imageReveal == "") {
                alert("Please enter some text!");
            } else {
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                rubberDuckie.innerHTML = "<img src=" + rubberDuckie + " />";

                var ul = document.getElementById("listItUp");
                ul.appendChild(li);
            }
            rubberDuckie.value = "";
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body style="background-color:yellow;">
    <div align="center">
        <header>
            <h1>Alan Sylvestre</h1>
        </header>

        <input type="text" id="textInput" size="50" placeholder="Enter Some Text">
        <input type="button" id="clicking" value="Add Image" onclick="imageReveal()">
    </div>

    <ul id="listItUp">

    </ul>

    <p id="pTags">

    </p>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: you have included jquery  script. Why not just use jquery to get the job done ?

Comment: How would you suggest doing that?

Comment: @karthikr An **old** version of jQuery, at that

Comment: You should probably refactor your code to make better use of jQuery, since you are including it...

Comment: It's included but he makes no use of it as far as I can see.

Comment: @meewoK `$(document).keypress(function(e) {`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to insert the image into an input(which you can't cause its an empty element). Just insert the image into the li.

```
li.innerHTML = "<img src=\"" + imageReveal + "\">";
```

Comment: The attribute's value needs quoted too

Comment: So what happens if there's spaces, quotes, or other special chars in `imageReveal`?

Comment: @Musa: I see now what I was doing wrong. Your modified code worked great and the page works exactly as planned now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You're already using jQuery, so take full advantage of its methods. Try using:

```
function imageReveal() {
    var rubberDuckie = $("#textInput");  // Get textbox element
    var imageReveal = rubberDuckie.val();  // Get textbox value
    if (!$.trim(imageReveal)) {  // If textbox is empty (after being trimmed of whitespace)
        alert("Please enter some text!");
    } else {  // If textbox has value
        var li = $("<li>");  // Create <li> element
        li.append($("<img>").attr("src", rubberDuckie));  // Add <img> element with src to the <li>
        $("#listItUp").append(li);  // Add the new <li> to the list
    }
    rubberDuckie.val("");  // Set the textbox value to empty
}
```

Also, your version of jQuery (1.3.2) is quite outdated. There are so many bug fixes, improvements and whatnot since then, that it is quite advisable to upgrade to a newer version. The current stable version is 1.9.1.

- 1.9.1 - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
- Latest - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

There are other milestone versions that would be acceptable to work with, but I like to stay with the newest version to have the "best" version out there.

Comment: This is the way to go...and you should probably link to the [latest jQuery version](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js).

Answer (score 0):

You actually only add a list item.

You need to add the list item in addition the image. For example, and most similar to your code:

```
 function imageReveal() {
            var rubberDuckie = document.getElementById("textInput");
            var imageReveal = rubberDuckie.value;
            if (imageReveal == "") {
                alert("Please enter some text!");
            } else {
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                var ul = document.getElementById("listItUp");
                ul.appendChild(li);
                li.innerHTML = "<img src=" + imageReveal + " />";
            }
            rubberDuckie.value = "";
        }
```

Comment: This worked great. I see exactly what I was doing wrong. Thank you for helping me figure this out!